# Encrypted Authentication request on an OpenSSO Server from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, authentication, opensso

I have an ASP.NET website that take care of the way the login process occurs and I want to redirect to a site that is protected by an OpenSSO server.

So when the user is authenticated in the ASP.NET Website, I have to retreive the corresponding OpenSSO token in order to redirect to the website protected by OpenSSO.

Actually, I'm able to retreive the OpenSSO token but the username/password are passed in clear !

```
http://myopenssoserver.com/opensso/identity/authenticate?username=myUserID&password=myPassword
```

Is it possible to pass an encrypted username/password for an authentication request onto the OpenSSO server in order to retrieve the token

Thanks a million for your answers

Comment: Have you tried POSTing to the same URL using HTTPS?

Comment: It is actually the alternative solution we find for this problem but we were wondering if there was a way to pass the parameters encrypted

Comment: Are you saying you want it encrypted to protect against man-in-the-middle attacks or that you want to prevent the actual end-user from reading the username and password?

Comment: In fact, posting the informations on a secure line allow to hide from the end user the user/password informations but do not restrict anybody to get those using tools like fiddler (or any other sniffer). So yes, I'm more concerned of man-in-the-middle attack types and any other security issues.

Comment: Use HTTPS to prevent man-in-the-middle. Network sniffers will only see the encrypted data. Fiddler will only see it if you enable HTTPS proxy debugging (in which case your browser will complain about untrusted SSL certs unless you've marked it as trusted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return a form that's set to POST the data to `https://myopenssoserver.com/opensso/identity/authenticate` and use JavaScript to make the browser automatically submit the form.

```
<form action="https://myopenssoserver.com/opensso/identity/authenticate" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="username" value="myUserId" />
  <input type="hidden" name="password" value="myPassword" />
</form>
```

This way, your data stays encrypted on the wire and is protected from man-in-the-middle attacks.

You could also include a submit button (inside a `<noscript>`, perhaps) for users with browsers where JavaScript is disabled or unavailable.